# debug-toolbar spoiled my urls

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar

I'm a newbie to Django and now I'm trying to make a simple webshop using it. Today I realized that I need some debug tool, so I've chosen `django-debug-toolbar`. I setup it just like it's explained here - [How do I see the Django debug toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390310/how-do-i-see-the-django-debug-toolbar). But when I set `DEBUG` to `True` I get a message -

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    Using the URLconf defined in urlconf, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    ^__debug__/m/(.*)$
    ^__debug__/sql_select/$ [name='sql_select']
    ^__debug__/sql_explain/$ [name='sql_explain']
    ^__debug__/sql_profile/$ [name='sql_profile']
    ^__debug__/template_source/$ [name='template_source']
    The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Here is my app's urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('ecommerce.views',
    url(r'^profile/$', 'profile'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'login_user'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'logout_user'),
    url(r'^registration/$', 'registration'),
)
```

As far as I can see now django looks for appropriate urls not in my app's urls.py, but somewhere else.

Comment: can you update the question with the full traceback, and the urls.py ?

Comment: Your requested url is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` and you do not have a URL target for `/`. What does your main urls.py look like ?

Comment: Please, can you post your `ROOT_URLCONF` in your `settings.py` and also the file it's pointing?

Comment: Thanks a lot! You have guided me on the right path.I edited my main urls.py like that:

    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
    
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^ecommerce/', include('ecommerce.urls'))
    )

and now browser gives the correct response.