# Django Debug Toolbar doesn't appear

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi, django-debug-toolbar

I think I have tried almost every solution on the web but the django debug toolbar still doesn't appear on my website. Difficult thing is that it doesn't give any error, or any sign from where I can find the issue.

I have tried automatic as well as manual installation. Following most common things tried:

1. added my ip to internal ips, even added `SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK = lambda x: True`
2. Ran the `collectstatic` command
3. checked for any html tags not closing in my pages
4. Confirmed that `debug=True` in settings.py

5) removed .pyc files

And so on..

**EDIT TO INCLUDE SETTINGS**

Settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
)

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PATCH_SETTINGS = False
SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK = lambda x: True
INTERNAL_IPS = ('bla','bla',)
```

myproject/myproject/urls.py:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    )
```

Comment: Can you show your relevant settings?

Comment: updating the answer with settings

Comment: these are all the relevant settings right?

Comment: Try moving `'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',` to the top of the list. Also, you haven't shown whether or not you have added `'debug_toolbar',` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`...

Comment: Is DEBUG set to true?

Comment: Debug is set to True, i have tried moving middleware to the top of the list and it didnt have an effect, and yes debug_toolbar is added to installed_apps..

Comment: Try to throw some exception for your app and check if all of your settings are correct on debug page.

Comment: The solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390310/how-do-i-see-the-django-debug-toolbar

Comment: Sometimes it could be occurred when your template does not have `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs of [`SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK`](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.3.2/configuration.html#debug-toolbar-config), it's value is not expected to be a function object:

> This is the dotted path to a function used for determining whether the toolbar should show or not.

I.e. try using a normal named function, and reference it with a string in your settings.

Example, in your_project/config.py

```
def show_always(request):
    return True
```

And then in settings:

```
SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK = 'your_project.config.show_always'
```

(Also, automatic setup did not work for me on one of two systems either, inexplicably; I had to use [explicit setup](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.3.2/installation.html#explicit-setup), but you're doing that already.)